# Print Text to Printer Ignoring Page Length Using VB

Tags: vb.net, printing

My task is this:

I need to print a string to a printer that will then be formatted appropriately using a third party program, PlanetPress. I have decided to use an XML format for better manipulation. My problem is that when I send my string to a printer, it appears to abide by the normal page width and height restrictions and cuts off any additional characters and lines. I need to be able to print a text file, no matter the length, and not have it manipulated in any way. Here is my code for printing:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Print
    Friend TextToBePrinted As String

    Public Sub print(ByVal text As String, ByVal printer As String)
        TextToBePrinted = text
        Dim print As New Printing.PrintDocument
        Using (print)
            print.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer
            AddHandler print.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
            print.Print()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        Dim myFont As New Font("Courier New", 9)
        args.Graphics.DrawString(TextToBePrinted, New Font(myFont, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 0, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is where I call it:

```
    Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

    Dim printer As New Print
    printer.print(Trim(strPrint), "\\nj-nt-ppress\capture")
```

And here is where I create my string to print. It's using an iteration through an objects collection member and strPrint is defined as a global variable:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim oJ As New clsJobs, oJM As clsJobs
    If Not oJ.ReadAllActiveJobs Then
        ' manage error
    Else
        Dim tr As TableRow, tc As TableCell, chk As CheckBox
        strPrint = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & Environment.NewLine
        strPrint = strPrint & "<JobSchedule>"
        strPrint = "<TimeStamp>'" & Now.ToString & "'</TimeStamp>"
        hdnScrollSpeed.Value = oJ.mCollection.Count
        For Each oJM In oJ.mCollection
            strPrint = strPrint & "<Job>"
            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.JobID
            tc.Visible = False
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.JobPriority
            tc.Font.Bold = True
            tc.CssClass() = "Priority"
            strPrint = strPrint & "<Priority>'" & oJM.JobPriority & "'</Priority>"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.JobNumber
            tc.CssClass() = "JobNumber"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            strPrint = strPrint & "<JobNumber>'" & oJM.JobNumber & "'</JobNumber>"
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.ItemNumber
            tc.CssClass() = "ItemNumber"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            strPrint = strPrint & "<ItemNumber>'" & oJM.ItemNumber & "'</ItemNumber>"
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.moItem.Description
            tc.CssClass() = "ItemDescription"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            strPrint = strPrint & "<ItemDescription>'" & SharedCode.StripCommas(oJM.moItem.Description) & "'</ItemDescription>"
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.moMold.MoldNumber
            tc.CssClass() = "Mold"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            'tc = New TableCell
            'tc.Text = oJM.moInsert.InsertLetter
            'tc.CssClass() = "Insert"
            'tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            strPrint = strPrint & "<Mold>'" & oJM.moMold.MoldNumber & "'</Mold>"
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.Quantity
            tc.CssClass() = "Quantity"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            strPrint = strPrint & "<Quantity>'" & oJM.Quantity & "'</Quantity>"
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Text = oJM.moMachine.MachineNumber
            tc.CssClass() = "Machine"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            strPrint = strPrint & "<Machine>'" & oJM.moMachine.MachineNumber & "'</Machine>"
            tc = New TableCell
            'chk = New CheckBox
            'chk.Checked = oJM.isRunning
            'chk.Enabled = False
            'tc.Controls.Add(chk)
            If oJM.isRunning Then
                tc.Text = "<img src='img/running.png' />"
            End If
            tc.CssClass() = "Running"
            tr.Cells.Add(tc)
            strPrint = strPrint & "<Running>'" & oJM.isRunning & "'</Running></Job>"
            tblMstrJobsList.Rows.Add(tr)
        Next
        strPrint = strPrint & "</JobSchedule>"
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I would post screenshots of the text file output but do not have enough reputation. 
I have looked at the string in debug and it has all the correct information. Once it is sent to the printer is when I lose data. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `it appears to abide by the normal page width and height restrictions and cuts off any additional characters and lines.`  I don't see where in your code you are setting any printer margins, etc.  You should probably print your text line by line vs sending the whole glob of text to the printer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that as well, to put a carriage return after every line but I had a similar issue where after about 72 lines, it cuts off. Would it work to declare no margins somewhere? Or Use a different way to print?

Comment: I already mentioned it: print your text line by line.  That would require you to loop through your lines and set the HasMorePages property if you have to continue printing to the next page.